# error: compareTo(Object) in Car cannot implement compareTo(T) in Comparable

Tags: java, interface, compareto

```
public int compareTo(Object another) throws CustomMadeException
{
    if(this.getClass() != another.getClass() )
    {
        throw new CustomMadeException();
    }

    Car other = (Car) another;


    return this.getBrand().compareTo(other.getBrand());


}
```

I don't understand what's wrong exactly with my code. Why can't it implement T in comparable? Do I have to change the argument of compareTo to T? But shouldn't it be Object? As far as I know, the implementation of compareTo in the interface comparable is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is as follows:

```
public class Car implements Comparable<Car> {

    ...

    public int compareTo(Car other)
    {
        return this.getBrand().compareTo(other.getBrand());
    }
}
```

Note that your implementation of `compareTo()` can't throw any checked exceptions, since none are permitted by the `Comparable<T>.compareTo()`'s `throws` specification.

Comment: ah ok, but shouldn't it be Object? it was Object for equals() right?

Comment: error: Car is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(Object) in Comparable

Comment: @user2089523: Are you implementing `Comparable<Car>` as per my answer?

Comment: but can i just use my method? i solved the problem without using Comparable<Car>

Answer (score 0):

First: Interfaces never contain implementations of a method.

Second: How does the implements statement of your class looks? If you use a generic type, then you have to use that type as parameter type in your method.

Example:
If you implement the interface like this:

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>
```

then your method must have the following signature:

```
public int compareTo(MyClass param)
```

Answer (score 0):

To override compareTo() method from Comparable interface, you cannot throw new or broader checked exception. Hence you are getting it all wrong. This is against the rules for overriding any method in java. Refer this link to know the rules for overriding in java : [Sample link](http://code.google.com/p/learn-java/wiki/OverridenMethod)

This is the reason why you are not able to implement T in comparable in your code, because compiler treats it as a different method and not the overridden one. But actually the problem is with overriding.